# How to implement a generic linked list map function in Rust?

Tags: generics, polymorphism, rust

I am cutting my teeth with Rust and I'm trying to implement a generically-typed linked list. So far my `cons` and `len` functions work but there is something wrong with `map` that I cannot figure out.

```
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum List<A> {
    Empty,
    Cons(A, Box<List<A>>),
}

fn cons<A>(x: A, xs: List<A>) -> List<A> {
    return List::Cons(x, Box::new(xs));
}

fn len<A>(xs: List<A>) -> i32 {
    match xs {
        List::Empty => 0,
        List::Cons(_, xs) => 1 + len(*xs),
    }
}

fn map<A, B>(f: &Fn(A) -> B, xs: List<A>) -> List<B> {
    match xs {
        List::Empty => List::Empty,
        List::Cons(x, xs) => cons(f(x), map(f, *xs)),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let xs = cons(1, cons(2, cons(3, List::Empty)));
    println!("{:?}", xs);
    println!("{:?}", len(xs));
    let f = |x: i32| x * x;
    println!("{:?})", map(f, xs));
}
```

**Error**

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:32:27
   |
32 |     println!("{:?})", map(f, xs));
   |                           ^ expected reference, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::ops::Fn(_) -> _`
              found type `[closure@src/main.rs:31:13: 31:27]`
```

**Expected Output**

```
Cons(1, Cons(2, Cons(3, Empty)))
3
Cons(1, Cons(4, Cons(9, Empty)))
```

My particular problem is with

```
println!("{:?})", map(f, xs));
```

If I comment that line out, the first two lines of output are correct. I'm not sure what's wrong with my `map` call

---

**Update**

aochagavia helped me understand the function reference issue and the first ownership issue (of many, apparently!) - I'm having trouble using the same technique we used in `len` in `map` and getting a new error

My updated `map` function looks like this

```
fn map<A, B>(f: &Fn(A) -> B, xs: &List<A>) -> List<B> {
    match *xs {
        List::Empty => List::Empty,
        List::Cons(x, ref xs) => cons(f(x), map(f, xs)),
    }
}
```

I'm now trying this

```
let f = |x: i32| x * x;
let ys = map(&f, &xs);
let zs = map(&f, &xs);
println!("{:?})", ys);
println!("{:?})", zs);
```

The new error is this

```
error[E0009]: cannot bind by-move and by-ref in the same pattern
  --> src/main.rs:23:20
   |
23 |         List::Cons(x, ref xs) => cons(f(x), map(f, xs)),
   |                    ^  ------ both by-ref and by-move used
   |                    |
   |                    by-move pattern here
```

Comment: *I am cutting my teeth with Rust* => Good luck :) It can be a bit of work at the beginning to wrap your head around ownership/borrowing but I promise it gets easier going forward! Don't hesitate to peruse SO when you have an issue, and if you need some discussions/advices that are not suitable here, you can hop in on IRC (https://chat.mibbit.com/?server=irc.mozilla.org&channel=%23rust-beginners), reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/) or the users forum (https://users.rust-lang.org/).

Comment: @MatthieuM.thank you for the warm welcome. I'm finding Rust to be very interesting so far, but yes, some of these things are really throwing me for a loop. Any language I've worked with so far doesn't have anything comparable (that I know of).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is big because it happens within a macro, but if you add this: `let y = map(f, xs);` you get a shorter (and slightly more accurate) one:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> <anon>:32:15
   |
32 |   let y = map(f, xs);
   |               ^ expected reference, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `&std::ops::Fn(_) -> _`
              found type `[closure@<anon>:31:11: 31:25]`
```

That is, you are passing the closure by value instead of by reference! Using `map(&f, xs)` (note the ampersand) should solve the error. However, there is another issue with ownership (see below).

### The ownership issue

The type signature of the `len` function is `fn len<A> (xs: List<A>) -> i32`. That means that it will take ownership of the list in order to calculate its length. This is however not what you want, since it would prevent you from using the list afterwards! Hence the error you get from the compiler.

The sensible way to solve this is to let `len` borrow `xs` instead of consuming it. Like this:

```
fn len<A>(xs: &List<A>) -> i32 {
    match *xs {
        List::Empty => 0,
        List::Cons(_, ref xs) => 1 + len(xs),
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need to modify your `main` function to reflect this change by calling `len` like this: `len(&xs)` (note the ampersand, which you can think of as the borrow operator).

### Making map borrow xs as well

As naomik pointed out in the comments, `map` seems to be a candidate as well for borrowing `xs` instead of consuming it. A possible implementation would be:

```
fn map<A, B>(f: &Fn(&A) -> B, xs: &List<A>) -> List<B> {
    match *xs {
        List::Empty => List::Empty,
        List::Cons(ref x, ref xs) => cons(f(x), map(f, xs)),
    }
}
```

The main difference with the original version is that the closure now takes an `&A` instead of an `A` (see `Fn(&A) -> B`). This is natural, since it is impossible to consume a value that is contained in a borrow (it would mean the borrow mechanism is utterly broken).

In main you would need to call `map` like this:

```
let f = |x: &i32| (*x) * (*x);
map(&f, &xs);
```

Note that `f` now borrows its parameter instead of consuming it, as is required by the type signature of `map`.

### Some extra background in closures

Closures are a bit special in Rust. You can construct them with a nice syntax, but in the end they are just structs that happen to implement the `Fn`, `FnMut` or `FnOnce` traits.

In case you want to pass them by value (and not by reference, as you do in your code), you can make the map function generic by using the following type signature:

```
fn map<F, A, B> (f: F, xs: List<A>) -> List<B>
    where F: Fn(A) -> B
{
```

This also gives you static dispatch. If you want to know more about that you should probably read on [trait objects and static/dynamic dispatch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html).

Comment: Ok thanks! I see the new ownership-related problem but I'm not sure it warrants an entirely separate question because this answer alone will not generate my expected output. Do you think you could help me with the ownership issue here too?

Comment: Interesting... OK, but wouldn't I want to make my `map` function *borrow* `xs` then too? eg, if I wanted to map over `xs` twice, it looks like the first call to map *moves* `xs` - it seems strange to have to be more explicit using borrowing operator when I'm not mutating the values in my functions. I get the idea that my code will have `&` before almost every parameter - and likewise `&` before each argument... does that seem right?

Comment: It depends. In this case it seems reasonable, so you should definitely try it out. Feel free to comment here if you need help.

Comment: updated my question to demonstrate my inability to take what you taught me about borrowing in `len` and apply it in `map` :(

Comment: yikes, it seems like i have a long way to go before this will start to feel natural in any sort of way. Right now my gut reaction is confusion when the *default* behavior of a function is to "consume" an argument. It seem like that should be called out explicitly like `mut` but *not* be consumed by default. I wonder how learning of Rust idioms will change this perspective over time... Anyway, thank you for handling my question so thoroughly. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It definitely takes some time to get to grips with ownership, but at some moment it does seem natural. It is like doing functional programming for the first time (e.g. how can I program without for loops!?). Feel free to drop by `#rust` on irc.mozilla.org for any questions you have!

Comment: I'm just about to sleep but I'll certainly join tomorrow. Thanks ^^